# How to plot and define with Matlab a function defined on different subintervals, which enters an ODE

Tags: matlab, plot

I am trying to plot and then to use it with `Matlab`
in an ODE as coefficient, the function

f : [2,500] -> [0,1], [image]

But I don't know how to write the code for the definition of the function, since it is given on different subintervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example that uses anonymous functions/function handles. It uses each region/condition and evaluates the boundaries numerically and stores them into variables `Bounds_1` and `Bounds_2`. These boundaries are then used to truncate each signal by multiplying each section of the piecewise function by its corresponding condition which is a logical array. It's also good to note that this plot will almost be seen as an impulse since the bounds are really small. Alternatively, you can probably achieve the same results using the built-in `piecewise()` function but I think this method gives a little more insight. As `i` increases you'll see a plot that resembles more and more of an impulse. **To plot this for multiple values or `i` this can be run in a for-loop**.

[image]

```
clc;
i = 3; 

Bounds_1 = [i - (1/i^2),i];
Bounds_2 = [i,i + (1/i^2)];
Bounds = [Bounds_1 Bounds_2];
Min = min(Bounds);
Max = max(Bounds);

f1 = @(x) (i^2.*x - i^3 + 1).*(Bounds_1(1) < x & x <= Bounds_1(2));
f2 = @(x) (-i^2.*x + i^3 + 1).*(Bounds_2(1) < x & x <= Bounds_2(2));

f = @(x) f1(x) + f2(x);

fplot(f);
xlim([Min-2 Max+2]);
ylim([0 1.1]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much Michael! Indeed, the plotting of the function on the interval centerd at i=3 is obtained. I would really appreciate if you could write the complete code for the function on the entire interval [2,500] (I am not too familiarized with MatLab). I also intend to use then the function as a time-depending coefficient in an ODE, so I think the expression of f should be specified...

Comment: I really don't know to use the function for-loop.

Comment: I'm just not sure the type you're expecting to make sure it'll work with your next step? An array, symbolic function or function handle/anonymous function.

Comment: After defining/plotting the function f(x) on the interval [2,500], I want to plot on [2,500] the solution of the second order ODE y''+f(x)y'+y=0 with the initial data y(2)=0.1, y'(2)=0.1. This is why I think we should know the function f(x) on the whole interval [2,500], before calling it in the ODE.

Comment: I tried to add a 'for' as follows.

`for i= 2:500
Bounds_1 = [i - (1/i^2),i];
Bounds_2 = [i,i + (1/i^2)];
Bounds = [Bounds_1 Bounds_2];
Min = min(Bounds);
Max = max(Bounds);
f1 = @(x) (i^2.*x - i^3 + 1).*(Bounds_1(1) < x & x <= Bounds_1(2));
f2 = @(x) (-i^2.*x + i^3 + 1).*(Bounds_2(1) < x & x <= Bounds_2(2));
f = @(x) f1(x) + f2(x); 
end
fplot(f);`

But it seems that the only plotted spike is for i=500 and it actually looks like an impulse.

Comment: Sound like you need something with mathematical rigor such as a symbolic function. Might be possible by using the `piecewise()` function built into MATLAB. The implementation will of course depend on how you're solving the Ordinary Differential Equation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution. You can specify the steps along the x-axis with`xstep`. With `xlower` and `xupper` you can specify the range of the x-axis:

```
figure ; hold on;
xlabel('x'); ylabel('f(x)');
for i= 2:500
    [f,x] = myfunction(0.5,i);
    plot (x,f,'DisplayName',sprintf('%i',i));
end
% legend

function [f,x]=myfunction(xstep,i)
%xstep: specifies steps for the x values
% specify max range x \in = [xlower -> xupper]
xlower = -10;
xupper = 600;
x2 = (i-1/i^2): xstep: i;
f2 = i^2*x2 - i^3 + 1;
x3 = i+xstep:xstep:(1+1/i^2);
f3 = -i^2*x3 + i^3 +1;
x1 = xlower:xstep:(i-1/i^2);
f1 = 0*x1;
x4 = (i+1/i^2):xstep:xupper;
f4 = 0*x4;
f = [f1,f2,f3,f4];
x = [x1,x2,x3,x4];
end
```

[Here is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75hw9.png)

Besides, I am not exactly sure what you mean with ODE (ordinary differential equation) in f(x). For me it seems like an algebraic equation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The function f(x) enters then as coefficient in the ordinary differential equation `y'' + f(x) y' + y = 0`, where `y'= dy/dx` and `y''= d^2y/dx^2`.